# Download data into named file with javascript with Chrome version > 73

Tags: javascript, file, download

I am attemting to download data into a named file with javascript.

```
function saveAs(uri, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = uri;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); // remove the link when done
        console.log("OK")
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}

var name = 'myfile.xyz';
var data = {hello: "world"};
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});

saveAs(blob, name);
```

It does not seem to work, even though I have seen people do this before. I find JS fiddles but they are broken as of 2019 - either no download or Chrome gives a broken download item:

> Failed - no file

My details:

```
Google Chrome   73.0.3683.86 (Officiell version) (64 bitar)
Version f9b0bec6063ea50ce2b71f5b9abbae7beee319a6-refs/branch-heads/3683@{#858}
OS  Mac OS X
JavaScript  V8 7.3.492.25
```

Comment: `console.log(typeof link.download)`

Comment: @James that yields "string"